# import multiple components with one Line (Next js)

Tags: import, next.js

I am trying to call multiple components into a page in the same line

[image: Component tree]

in the index.js file, it is importing the components and exporting them

```
import Header from "./Header/Header";
import Navbar from "./Navbar/Navbar";

const exportedObject = {
    Header,
    Navbar,
};

export default exportedObject;
```

and adding the imports to the page

```
import { Header, Navbar } from "../components";

        <div>
            <Header title="about page" />
            <Navbar />
            <h1>About</h1>
            <p>THIS is the about page</p>
        </div>
```

I keep getting this error

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

trying to get it working this set-up but I don't know what I have done wrong

EDIT:
this is how I am exporting the files

```
export function Navbar() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>this is a navbar</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the index file

```
export * from "./Header/Header";
export * from "./Navbar/Navbar";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should export default your component

```
export default function Navbar() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>this is a navbar</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

and remove default export in exportedObject component

```
const exportedObject = {
    Header,
    Navbar,
};

export exportedObject;
```

Comment: tried that, still getting the same error :'(

Comment: if you default you cant use {}

Comment: @beginnersLuck.css I haved update my answer, can you check?